# How save data from DropDownList to db

Tags: .net, asp.net-core

I have the following Action method:

```
    //POST: Employees/Create
    [HttpPost]
    //[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromBody] Employee employee)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _context.Add(employee);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }

        **ViewData["PositionId"]** = new SelectList(_context.Positions, "PositionId", "PositionId", employee.PositionId);
        return View(employee);
    }
```

and on the view i am trying to render drop-down list:

```
<div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Position" class="control-label"></label>
                @Html.DropDownList("PositionId", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["PositionId"])
                <span asp-validation-for="Position" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
```

and i see next error
when I fill the form data and click save in console i see that PositionId is null, but i filled this field.
This is ajax method

```
$("body").on("click", "#save", function () {
    var form = $('form');
    var token = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]', form).val();
    var data_ = {
        FistName: $("#FistName").val(),
        LastName: $("#LastName").val(), 
        Position: $("#PositionId").val(),    
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: form.attr('action'),
        data: JSON.stringify(data_),
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (result) {
            $("#add-employee").modal("hide");
            $("#partial").html(result);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

this is my model

```
public class Employee
    {
        [Key] 
        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
        public string FistName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public int PositionId { get; set; }
        public Position Position { get; set; }
    }
public class Position
    {
        [Key]
        public int PositionId { get; set; }
        public string PositionName { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    }
```

How it fix? i cant save this position into db(

Comment: Have you tried it without the `Html.DropDownList`: `asp-items="@((IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["PositionId"])"`?

Comment: without it show correctly, but when i SAVE nothing happens `<div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="Position" class="control-label"></label>
@Html.DropDownList("PositionId", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["PositionId"])
                        <span asp-validation-for="Position" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>`

Comment: when I click save, the post request does not see the Position

https://i.imgur.com/3a0CR48.jpg

Answer (score 0):

The first thing is make sure you get correctly `$("#PositionId").val()` , you can test with `alert($("#PositionId").val())` in your js function . Property name should match during model binding , so you should modify :

```
Position: $("#PositionId").val(),
```

To :

```
PositionId: $("#PositionId").val(),
```

If you are working with ASP.NET Core 3.0+ , you can parse the value to int because of using `system.text.json` :

```
PositionId: parseInt($("#PositionId").val(),10),
```